# When SSL is enabled, Spark UI doesn't use HTTPS, but forwards to port 0 over HTTP

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

We are using Spark 2.0.2 and Hadoop 3.2.1. I have gotten SSL configured across Hadoop without any trouble. But Spark is having some trouble.

Without SSL, I can launch a job and view the Spark UI, proxied through Yarn.

When I enable SSL, I can still launch a job and run to completion, but I can not access the Spark Web UI. Yarn links to an ApplicationMaster proxy that fails with `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

Digging into the job's stdout, I see lines like this:

```
2020-04-14 16:21:57,258 INFO server.ServerConnector: Started ServerConnector@1484944f{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:40809}
2020-04-14 16:21:57,303 INFO server.ServerConnector: Started ServerConnector@799e8b3a{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:36015}
2020-04-14 16:21:57,303 INFO server.Server: Started @5614ms
2020-04-14 16:21:57,304 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 40809.
2020-04-14 16:21:57,309 INFO ui.SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at https://10.10.75.40:40809
```

If I call up `https://10.10.75.40:40809` I get an error that it isn't SSL.

If I call up `http://10.10.75.40:40809` I get served a bogus redirect to port 10.10.75.40:0.

If I call up `https://10.10.75.40:36015` and ignore certificate errors, or if I call via the correct hostname, I get redirected to the RM's `:8090/proxy/redirect` which throws the 500 error again.

My configuration consists of:

```
spark.ssl.enabled                 true
spark.ssl.keyStore                /etc/sslmate/STAR.mtv.qxxxxxxxxd.com.jks
spark.ssl.keyStorePassword        _the password_
spark.ssl.trustStore              /etc/sslmate/STAR.mtv.qxxxxxxxxd.com.jks
spark.ssl.trustStorePassword      _the password_
spark.ssl.protocol                TLSv1.2
```

I have also experimented with trying to set ports explicitly, to no avail:

```
spark.ssl.ui.port                 4440
spark.ssl.history.port            18480
spark.ui.driver.port              2020
spark.ssl.ui.driver.port          2420
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find this documented via Apache, but I found [a note from MapR](https://mapr.com/docs/61/Spark/ConfigureSparkOnYarn_Encryption.html) that got me working:

> Spark UI SSL is not needed when running Spark on YARN because encryption is provided by the YARN protocol. To disable Spark SSL, add `spark.ssl.ui.enabled false` to the `spark-defaults.conf` file on each spark node.

When configured in this manner, the ResourceManager correctly provides the Spark UI via a `:8090/proxy/redirect` type URL. In the `stderr` I see output along these lines:

```
2020-04-14 17:36:38,098 INFO server.ServerConnector: Started ServerConnector@7ef020c8{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:45951}
2020-04-14 17:36:38,098 INFO server.Server: Started @7871ms
2020-04-14 17:36:38,107 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 45951.
2020-04-14 17:36:38,113 INFO ui.SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.10.31.230:45951
```